# How to modify a Google Script that applies a formula to just a designated number of rows instead of applying it to an entire column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've got a script that applies my exact formula to column 'S' and it works perfectly. The only issue I have is that my google sheet has 50,000+ rows of data so it keeps crashing. (I've set this up via a time trigger so it's not my browsers fault).

My thinking is that if I modify this script to only be applied to rows 2 to 10,000 and then create another duplicate script to apply the formula to rows 10,001 to 20,000 and so on. This would break up the process and allow the full formula to be applied without crashing. I'm just not sure on how I modify the code to do so.

```
function settingFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var column = 19; // Column S index
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, sheet.getLastRow() - firstRow + 1);
  var formulas = range.getValues().map((row, index) => {
    let rowIndex = index + firstRow;
    return ["=JOIN(\", \",FILTER(N:N,B:B=R" + rowIndex + "))"];
  });
  range.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up modifying the script slightly which seems to of done the trick. It's not thrown up an errors... yet.

```
function settingFormulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var firstRow = 2;
  var column = 19; // Column S index
  var lastRow = 10000;
  var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, lastRow - firstRow + 1);
  var formulas = range.getValues().map((row, index) => {
    let rowIndex = index + firstRow;
    return ["=JOIN(\", \",FILTER(N:N,B:B=R" + rowIndex + "))"];
  });
  range.setFormulas(formulas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can just change the number of rows to edit when defining the range.*

#### Code Modification:

```js
var firstRow = 2;
var column = 19; // Column S index
var noOfRows = 9999;

var range = sheet.getRange(firstRow, column, noOfRows);
```

#### Points to remember:

- You will need to manage this so that you change `firstRow` for each script (this should be `firstRow + noOfRows` from the last script run)
- You will need to make sure that for the last script, `firstRow + noOfRows` ***does not exceed*** the value returned by `sheet.getLastRow()`.

Comment: Thanks @Rafa Guillermo, I tried adding this to my code but it made no difference. I presume this is down to my implementation rather than your script.